# Are there nonstandard $\mathsf{PA}$ models without $\Delta^1_1$ cuts?

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models, second-order-logic

My question is the following:

> Is there a nonstandard model $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{PA}$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ has no $\Delta^1_1$-with-parameters-definable nonempty proper successor-closed initial segments ("cuts")?

Here "$\Delta^1_1$" is meant in the sense of the **standard semantics** of second-order logic - so a $\Delta^1_1$ subset of $\mathcal{M}$ doesn't need to be "internal" to $\mathcal{M}$ in any nice sense.

If we replace $\Delta^1_1$ with $\Pi^1_1$ the answer is trivially negative since the cut of standard naturals is $\Pi^1_1$; no parameters are needed here. If we replace $\Delta^1_1$ with $\Sigma^1_1$ this answer again becomes negative since for each nonstandard $a\in\mathcal{M}$ the set of elements infinitely below $a$ is $\Sigma^1_1(a)$ over $\mathcal{M}$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4036011/28111).) However, I don't see a way to get a $\Delta^1_1$ cut in a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$. On the other hand, I don't see how to build a nonstandard model without a $\Delta^1_1$ cut. In particular, a natural hope might be to look at a nontrivial ultrapower of $\mathbb{N}$, but while $\Sigma^1_1$ formulas are preserved by taking ultrapowers, $\Delta^1_1$-ness (= an equivalence between a $\Sigma^1_1$ formula and a $\Pi^1_1$ formula) doesn't obviously need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have posted [a complete answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385315/83901) on MathOverflow.

The general idea of the solution is that sufficiently saturated models will always fail to have $\Delta^1_1$ definable cuts, even with parameters. Computably saturated countable models should also be sufficient, which avoids set theoretic assumptions.

Comment: I wonder what's the shortest time interval between answer posting and bounty awarding - for the record, this was 8 seconds by my computer.